# Watchers not getting canceled - how to do a finally-cancelled detection on takeEvery

Tags: redux-saga

I start multiple "watchers" like this:

```
yield allMyTasks = [fork(fooWatcher), fork(barWatcher), fork(bazWatcher), fork(quxWatcher)];
```

These all start a `takeEvery` like this:

```
function* fooWatcher() {
    try {
        yield takeEvery('FOO', fooWorker);
    } finally {
        if (yield cancelled()) {
            console.log('fooWatcher was cancelled');
        }
    }
}
```

On logout, I cancel `allMyTasks` like this:

```
yield cancel(...allMyTasks);
```

However none of the `finally` blocks are happening due to `cancelled`. Is there anyway to detect cancel on watcher?

I tested dispatching `FOO` to test if the `takeEvery` is still alive after `cancel` and noticed that even though the `finally-cancelled` does not trigger, the `takeEvery` really doesn't respond. So it really was canceled huh? Is this observation correct? This is what i was hoping for, but i needed to do a `finally-cancelled` when the takeEvery gets cancelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is the `takeEvery` helper is non blocking, so the interpreter doesn't wait inside the `try` block and the code in the `finally` block is called immediately when the saga is run.

For the `cancelled` effect to work you need to be still waiting in the `try` block on something.

There might be a smarter way to write this, but one way to achieve what you want is to wait for a promise that is never going to be resolved/rejected. (Watch out for possible Promise timeout some Promise libs might have on by default).

```
function* fooWatcher() {
    try {
        yield takeEvery('FOO', fooWorker);
        yield new Promise(()=>{});
    } finally {
        if (yield cancelled()) {
            console.log('fooWatcher was cancelled');
        }
    }
}
```

Waiting for an action that is never going to be dispatched could work also, although I still think there is some other obvious way to just wait forever.

Comment: Thanks Martin this is interesting. Yeah it would be awesome for some other way, but I accepted this :)

Comment: Also is it true that the `takeEvery` is getting cancelled, even though Im not get a catch on it. It seems after i cancel the parent thing in `yield [...., takeEveryWatcher, ..]` that this `takeEvery` stop responding.

Comment: Yeah, takeEvery is non blocking because it uses `fork` internally, but the `cancel` cancels even all forked tasks.

Comment: You can now use "join" to wait/block on a task